# HTML form browser side checkbox and jQuery datepicker entry check

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a javascript form checking problem that I cannot solve...

I have a form that needs browser side checking before it allows the user to click the submit button.

The form has been simplified for this example. There is a jQuery datepicker entry and a checkbox.

I need the browser to check whether at least the datepicker input box has an entry in it OR the checkbox is ticked before allowing the submit button to be pressed. If the checkbox AND the datepicker box has an entry, that is fine because the insert_sql_row.php processing script will deal with that.

Note: This is not a case of putting 'required' in the datepicker section because if the checkbox is ticked then no date entry is required but the 'required' attribute will prevent the form being submitted.

Code example below;

```
<!-- jQuery datepicker script -->
<script>
$(function () 
    {
       var date = new Date();
       var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
       var currentDate = date.getDate();
       currentDate = currentDate;
       var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

       $('#datepicker1').datepicker(
       {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
       }); 
  });
</script>


<!-- test code for date / no date needed options -->
<form method="POST" action="insert_sql_row.php">

<b>Pick date:</b>
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date_entry" maxlength="10" size="10" />

<b>OR No Date Needed: </b>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1">

<input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit form"></td></tr>');

</form>
```

Many Thanks,
Matt.

Comment: "check whether at least the datepicker input box has an entry in it OR the checkbox is ticked before allowing the submit button to be pressed." Have you actually tried that yet? Pretty much spells out what you have to do.

Comment: Where is the validation code? or are you asking for that here?

Comment: @Epodax: Sorry your right, not PHP. Tag removed.

Comment: @RobFoley: Yes I am looking for the javascript to do that as my js skills are rubbish.

Comment: @GHOST93: I'm not looking for validation code, just a check that either the checkbox or the datepicker has a value in either one before the submit button can be clicked. I think I was clear on that above :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Html** should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" onchange="checkChange(this);">

<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date_entry" maxlength="10" size="10" required />
```

and **Script**

```
funciton checkChange(thisObj)
{
   if($(thisObj).is(":checked"))
   {
       $("#datepicker1").removeAttr("required");
   }else {
       $("#datepicker1").attr("required");
    }
    //rebind datepicker after changing required attribute
    $("#datepicker1").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the 'required' attribute is not being set on the datepicker, I checked with Firebug. I've tried modifying the code, including using coding ideas form numerous stack exchange QAs on the same subject, but I cannot seem to get the attribute to dynamically change. :-(

Comment: don't check it with firebug as your datepicker binded at DOM. Changing value with inspect will not be same output for set required for datepicker binded.

Comment: Problems is when you set required attribute you have to rebind "datepicker1" to datepicker. Please check my edited code for "rebind datepicker"